# Merging data from two excel spreadsheets

Tags: excel

I have two Excel spreadsheets.

One has a list of Student Names and Student Numbers (Columns A,B,C)

```
Johnson, Joe,   1001
Campbell, Pete, 1002
Reed, Eric,     5004
```

The other file has just the names (Columns A,B):

```
Reed, Eric 
Johnson, Joe
Campbell, Pete
```

Column A = last Name, Column B = First Name, Column C = Student Number (in file A)

I need to insert the corresponding student numbers into file b, so that it looks the same as file A.

The reason I can't copy/paste is because file a contains a whole bunch of names that are not in file b, and neither are in the correct order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See example below of a two-column lookup using INDEX and MATCH.  Simplified a little since both sets of data are on the same sheet...

Don't forget to use Ctrl+Shift+Enter when entering it, since it's an array-type formula.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, TIm. This is exactly what I needed. Appreciate the help.